# Some question on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nonsingular curve. In the proof of Theorem(V.2.17) of hartshorne book, I see the following statment:

We have only to take maps $\mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-e)$ and $\mathcal{O}(n-e) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n-e)$ corresponding to effective divisors of degrees $n-e$ and $n$ on $C$ which do not meet. Then the corresponding map $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(-e) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n-e) $ is be surjective.

My questions is that how define the above maps? and why last map is surjective?

Comment: This question is really unclear. Can you give a reference to where this appears in Hartshorne? The maps you wrote definitely do not look correct, and the last sentence of the "statemen" must be missing something (then the corresponding map _what_?)

Comment: Sorry, I will edit... I see that hartshorne book Theorem (V.2.17)